# Gnome3/cinnamon set keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3, cinnamon

I cannot find where I can set keyboard shortcut for switching languages.

**Update:**
New problem: I cannot set <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> combination for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't use `Cinnamon` so this might not work for you, but in *vanilla* `Gnome 3.6` you could do this either via terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.keyboard input-sources-switcher alt-shift-l
```

or via `dconf-editor`, navigating to `org` > `gnome` > `settings-daemon` > `peripherals` > `keyboard` and entering `alt-shift-l` as a value for the `input-sources-switcher` key:

[image]

In `Gnome 3.8` they have re-added this feature to `Settings` > `Keyboard` > `Shortcuts`, via an additional section called `Typing`:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

From language-bar select *"Keyboard Layout settings"*, *"Region and Language Settings"* or the like. Then select:

```
Layouts -> Options ... -> Key(s) to change layout
```

Check off desired key-combination.

---

If language-bar is not present go to:

```
Menu -> (System tools)* -> System Settings -> Keyboard -> Typing
```

click on *"Layout Settings"*.

<sup>`*`*Depending on menu layout "System Settings" is at top-level of menu or in sub of System tools.*</sup>

---

Or, from command-line, Run menu etc., execute:

```
gnome-control-center keyboard
```

click on *"Layout Settings"*.

---

***Tested on system with Gnome3/Cinnamon.***

#### EDIT :

You are not following the instructions. I try again with more pictures ;)

Pictures from Gnome 3 Classic, but was same for Gnome 3 / Cinnamon.

`1.` *Menu -> (System tools)<sup>1</sup> -> System Settings* – Select *Keyboard*:

<sup>*1*</sup> *Depending on menu layout.*

Quickest / fastest way could be:

```
$ gnome-control-center keyboard
```

[image]

`2.` Select *"Layout Settings"*:

[image]

`3.` Select *Layouts* 
`4.` Select *Options…*

[image]

`5.` Select *Key(s) to change layout* 
`6.` Check of desired key combination. ***And*** make sure there are no other selected (unwanted) combinations.

[image]

Note that for Cinnamon 3.2.7 (Linux Mint 18.1) The option is called **"Switching to another layout"**

Comment: Thanks, I found it, but cannot set `alt+shift` combination. Only with some another key. Can I do this with some config?

Comment: What do you mean by *cannot*? It isn't there or …? Here it works with both `Alt+Shift`, `Left Alt + Left Shift` etc.

Comment: I try typing `alt+shift` but nothing happens. `Alt`, `Control` and `Shift` keys set only if I use it with some another button.

Comment: You have to check it of with your mouse. Also remember to **remove** any old selections. Here it works with e.g. `Left Alt` alone.

Comment: My keyboard settings looks like this: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-nZCRySMxpMc/T9VAH3nKrpI/AAAAAAAADew/gbKeijQNUEI/s1600/gsc_1.png

Comment: @Xedar: That is not the keyboard settings I instructed. You have to follow what I write ;). Updated with more pictures.

Comment: thanx, but it's not what I need. I do the same as you say. I'll try to use Gnome3 with cinnamon, not Gnome2. I think it's reason why I cannot follow from your instructions.

Comment: … Well, Q is tagged "Gnome 3" not "Gnome 2" – thus I assumed it was Gnome 3 you worked with.